# Selenium C# Locate Both Data QA Attribute And CSS Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, xpath, css

How do we locate both Data QA Id and CSS Class using Selenium C# ?

We're trying to locate both a DataQAid attribute and also see if its class ng-invalid, (Angular Material Textbox Error)

This is what wrote so far:

```
private By PhoneError => By.XPath("//*[@attr.data-qa='homephone']");
```

[image]

**Resource:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120263/find-element-in-selenium-using-xpath-or-css-selector

Comment: is your locator working ? why are using `@attr.data-qa` instead of `@data-qa`

Comment: Why do you use 'homephone' when the value is 'homephone-update' ?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal are you aware of attr.data-qa ? Is it something new or even that is wrong . I never seen such a usage .

Comment: @PDHide No, I think it is a miss interpretation of examples

Answer (score 1):

```
By.XPath("//*[@data-qa='homephone-update' and @class='ng-invalid']");
```

Try this

Comment: This answers the how to use both attr and class. I do not think it solves the issue of the OP, as the data-qa field is homephone-update.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal thanks Niel i updated it , i didnt notice the remainingg